# how to align two textfields?

Tags: html, alignment

I have an HTML code as follows

```
<body>
    Hello UserName:<input tyep="text"/><br/>
    Pass:<input type="text"/>
</body>
```

I want the two text fields should be aligned in such a way that their left borders should start from the same positions of two lines.Because as it is if I runs the two text fields starts exactly after their labels ends, which I don't want as it looks odd.
How would I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at [this](http://www.futurecolors.ru/blog/wp-content/uploads/2009/07/lines.html) example with Chrome Developer Tools or Firebug.

*HTML:*

```
<div class="main">
    <div class="field">
        <label for="n">Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="n" />
    </div>
    <div class="field">
        <label for="ln">Surnemt</label>
        <input type="text" name="ln" />
    </div>
    <div class="field">
        <label for="a">Bithplace</label>
        <input type="text" name="a" />
    </div>
</div>
```

*CSS:*

```
body {font-size:14px;}
label {float:left; padding-right:10px;}
.field {clear:both; text-align:right; line-height:25px;}
.main {float:left;}
```